# Detecting the value on input

Tags: javascript, events

Having an input element

```
<input type="text">
```

if i add `keydown` event on it , it will work with state x - 1 value of input e.g

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
x.addEventListener("keydown",function(){
    alert(x.value);
},false);
```

if i input "a" , it will print empty string , when i add "b" it wont print "ab" but "a" ( state - 1 )

Is there any simple way how to retrieve current value not previous?

Comment: You can use `keyup` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `input` instead of `keydown` event.

If you require older [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event) then you should also listen for `keyup` and `mouseup` (drag/drop) events.

Answer (score 2):

Use `keyup` event or `keypress` event.

Reason is simple, when you are typing, there are three states.

1. When the key is pressed and held(even for a very short time). Here, the input field is not yet updated. This is `keydown`
2. `keyup` is when the key is released. That is when the input field is updated.
3. `keypress` is `keydown` and `keyup` both combined. (For alphanumeric keys)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in other answers, you can use `keyup` or `keypress` or `input` *if* you don't need to cancel event.
If you do need to cancel event (conditionally) then keydown is the must.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
x.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    //alert(x.value);
    console.log(x.value + String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode);
},false);
```

The event doesn't support character value but you can receive it from keyCode.